# JavaScript - replace setTimeout with async / await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

First, I know this is a common question. I'm trying to get a handle on how to use async / await in place of setTimeouts, but all the examples I see online use a setTimeout to simulate the async. This throws me off when it's a set timeout that I'm trying to replace.

In the function below, I want `this.filteredResults`to await the results of an API call before trying to filter those results and assign it to `this.filteredResults`.

```
getResults() {
  let allResults= airtableQuery.getTable("Transfers"); // API call using imported 'getTable' function

  console.log(allResults); // returns full array ▶[] although it's not available for filtering yet.

  setTimeout(() => { // I want to replace this timeout
    this.filteredResults = allResults.filter(
      (result) => result.fields.User === "dev"
    );
  }, 250); // random ms that is roughly how long airtableQuery takes for the API call.
},
```

And the airtableQuery:

```
getTable(table) {
  let recordsArr = [];
  base(`${table}`)
    .select({
      maxRecords: 8000,
    })
    .eachPage(
      function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
        records.forEach((record) => {
          recordsArr.push(record);
        });
        fetchNextPage();
      },
      function done(err) {
        if (err) {
          this.$toasted.error(err);
        }
      }
    );
  return recordsArr;
},
```

Comment: The reason your seeing the full array in the console is due to the way the console works. If you would try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(allResults))`, you'd see an empty array.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks, that's half the mystery :) I changed my question since it's kind of a separate question.

Comment: You'd need to provided the semantics of `airtableQuery.getTable()` for anyone to be able to write a decent answer.

Comment: [Someone]'s out here spamming downvotes because [they don't] know how async/await works.

Comment: @Christian I'm the one spamming downvotes because all answers so far have been bad.

Comment: To be fair, it was a bad question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen imported API function added to question.

Comment: `async/await` serves a completely different purpose from `setTimeout`. `await` is used to write code that looks synchronous when it's actually async. `setTimeout` is used to make something run at a later time, so it's inherently asynchronous.

Comment: @KirkRoss What you need to be looking for here is to convert your `allTable()` function to fit the `async`/Promise mold. Then you can just `await` the results of that function, and get rid of the timeout entirely.

Comment: The reason you often see `setTimeout` in questions about promises is because it's a simple way to create something that runs asynchronously. Most async functions involve external servers.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - what is the purpose of downvoting every single answer if we are just trying to give solutions, given limited information. `Async/await` would work just fine if `getTable()` was an actual `Promise` as it could be indicated from the initial question.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki If you don't have enough information, you ask for clarification or you vote to close the question as needing more details or clarity. Taking shots in the dark doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen in most cases that would work right away. I do not see the reason for being so negative. You can always edit the answer given additional information in the comment section under the answer until you get it right.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki What's the rush to post an answer? Your first answer 1) did not answer the question, and 2) was syntactically incorrect. If that doesn't deserve a down-vote, what does? I'll remove the down-vote because at least the syntax error is fixed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Correct, that is my bad. For that reason, I edited it right away. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the outer function an `async` function and then `await` the results before filtering them.

```
async function getResults() {
      let allResults = await airtableQuery.getTable("Transfers");
       this.filteredResults = allResults.filter(
         (result) => result.fields.User === "dev"
       );
},
```

Given that `getTable()` is not a `Promise`, `await` will not do anything. For that reason, we can make `getTable()` return a `Promise` which will resolve with `recordsArr`.

```
getTable(table) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let recordsArr = [];
        base(`${table}`)
            .select({
                maxRecords: 8000,
            })
            .eachPage(
                function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
                    records.forEach((record) => {
                        recordsArr.push(record);
                    });
                    fetchNextPage();

                },
                function done(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        this.$toasted.error(err);
                        reject(err)
                    }else {
                        resolve(recordsArr)
                    }
                }
            );
    })
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that actually and when I `console.log(allResults.length);` it still says zero length.

Comment: I appreciate it. I hope I did not cause you too much nerve. My apologies again - thanks for giving me the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Ah don't worry about me. I'm 10,000% not worth it :P Good that we could work together and get to an accepted answer for this question.

Comment: Haha :P You are good, man. Yes, we got that right in the end, phew...

Answer (score 0):

i always likes primise,this my code show you

```
getTable(table) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let recordsArr = [];
        base(`${table}`)
            .select({
                maxRecords: 8000,
            })
            .eachPage(
                function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
                    records.forEach((record) => {
                        recordsArr.push(record);
                    });
                    fetchNextPage();
                    res(recordsArr)
                },
                function done(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        this.$toasted.error(err);
                        rej(err)
                    }
                }
            );
    })
}
```

```
getResults() {
  airtableQuery.getTable("Transfers").then(res => {
    let allResults = res
    console.log(allResults);
    this.filteredResults = allResults.filter(
      (result) => result.fields.User === "dev"
    );
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I think you're close. Probably only need to resolve the promise on done. @KirkRoss what API is `eachPage()` part of? Does it take 3 callbacks (data, error, done)?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm not sure. `eachPage()` is part of the airtable.js library. IN the end, Jakub's answer ended up working, but thank you kindly for your thoughtful responses.